# Помогите установить xen на linux scientific 6.1

Tags: xen, linux

Итак, суть проблемы. Имею песочницу с linux scientific 6.1. Хочу воткнуть туда xen.

На страничке википедии это:

> Scientific Linux может использоваться для создания рабочей среды пользователя, разработчика, администратора. В состав дистрибутива входят компоненты для поддержки виртуализации Xen. В дистрибутив включен полный набор программных компонентов для организации серверной инфраструктуры как для внутренней сети, так и для Интернет

Запрос в гугле привел сюда: [Xen on Scientific Linux Howto](http://project-xen.web.cern.ch/project-xen/xen/howto_slcXen.html).

Начал ставить по этому ману.

> `[root@pupkin huita]# rpm -ivh xen-kernel-2.6.12-xen3_12.1_slc4.1.i686.rpmошибка: Неудовлетворенные зависимости:    kernel < 2.6.18 конфликтует с initscripts-9.03.23-1.el6.i686    kernel < 2.6.17 конфликтует с hal-0.5.14-11.el6.i686`

Если снести initscripts (~600 mb), то перестает работать в системе почти всё. Помогите, пожалуйста. Внятной инфы в инете не нашел.

Answer (score 1):

В Scientific манагер пакетов Yum :

```
yum list |moreyum list |grep xenyum install kernel-xen xen etc ...
```

Comment: Не всё так просто))На grep xen он мне выводит только "netxen-firmware"... вот так.Я еще буду искать, если найду - отпишусь.

Comment: Возможно нужно подкл репозиторий с xen

Comment: если нету то только один вариант git ом тащить xen-source и компилить ядро с xen ом

Comment: да и еще если xen будит использоваться под домашний пк с gui(gnome кеды) проприетарные драва на видяху прикрутить почти не реально

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, каким дистрибутивом вы пользуетесь, но на сайте описан способ для Fedora.В Debian я бы сделал так:

```
sudo apt-get updateaptitude search xen - выбираем нужный пакетsudo aptitude install xen(выбранный пакет)
```

Comment: Scientific - дистрибутив.В Scientific нет команды aptitude.